# How to highlight the selected node in treeview(jquery)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, treeview

```
.treeview ul {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
.treeview a:visited {
    background-color:  Yellow;
}
.treeview a:active {
    background-color:  Yellow;
}

.treeview a:selected {
    background-color:  Yellow;
}
```

As i click on the node the active css doesn't work because of postback. How do i highlight the clicked active node  and css shouldnot  get effected due to postback?

Comment: Where is jquery here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on Server Control on the **ASPX** Page

```
<asp:TreeView id="LinksTreeView"
                Font-Names= "Arial"
                ForeColor="Blue"
                SelectedNodeStyle-ForeColor="Green"
                SelectedNodeStyle-VerticalPadding="0"
                OnSelectedNodeChanged="Select_Change"   
                runat="server">
```

**Reference**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx

**jQuery**

```
$(".treeview a").click(function(){ 
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "blue");
});
```

Comment: $(".treeview a").click(function () {
                 alert("Rohit");
                 $(this).css("background-color", "orange");
             });

It's not working, neither the alert